# What is the difference between quadruple multiplexer and and the regular multiplexer?

Tags: cpu-architecture, boolean-logic

I know that a multiplexer takes input values, selection lines and produce one output.
My question here, what a quadruple 2x1 multiplexer is? and how does it differ from the regular multiplexers?

Comment: It is just an integrated circuit which contains four 2x1 multiplexers. Example is [IC 74157](http://www.ti.com/product/SN74157).

Comment: This belongs on http://electronics.stackexchange.com/